# What are the original default files contained in the /usr/share folder?

Tags: filesystem, directory, default

Can someone please just give me a list of the default files and folders that you would find in `/usr/share` folder after installation?

You would not believe how difficult this is to find.

Comment: You mean that it is "difficult to find" what files are by default in X folder, right?

Comment: no the whole usr/share folder ive been figting a bloody mega viurs and ive pinpointed it down finaly to this folder but i need to know what files are original and what ones are corrupt

Comment: If that is the case: re-install.

Answer (score 2):

Install Ubuntu in a virtual machine, or on a cheap virtual private server, then look.

Answer (score 0):

Default list of folders in `/usr/share`:

```
aclocal
acpi-support
adduser
alsa
alsa-base
app-install
applications
apport
apps
apt
aptdaemon
apt-xapian-index
aspell
avahi
backgrounds
base-files
base-passwd
binfmts
brltty
bug
ca-certificates
calendar
cogl
color
command-not-found
common-licenses
computerjanitor
consolefonts
console-setup
consoletrans
contractor
cups
dbus-1
debconf
debhelper
debianutils
defoma
desktop-directories
dict
dictionaries-common
djvu
doc
doc-base
dpkg
emacs
empathy
enchant
espeak-data
evince
evolution-data-server-3.2
farstream
file
file-roller
fonts
foo2qpdl
foo2zjs
foomatic
gala
gcalctool
gconf
GConf
gcr-3
gdb
gdm
geany
geoclue-providers
GeoIP
ghostscript
ginn
gir-1.0
gksu
glib-2.0
gnome
gnome-bluetooth
gnome-control-center
gnome-keyring-3
gnome-panel
gnome-power-manager
gnome-screenshot
gnome-session
gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-user-share
gnome-vpn-properties
gnupg
groff
grub
grub-gfxpayload-lists
gst-plugins-base
gst-python
gstreamer-0.10
gtk-doc
gtk-engines
gtksourceview-3.0
gutenprint
gvfs
hal
help
help-langpack
hplip
hunspell
hwdata
i18n
ibus
ibus-pinyin
ibus-table
icons
im-switch
indicator-application
indicator-datetime
indicators
info
initramfs-tools
initscripts
insserv
iptables
java
javascript
jockey
keyrings
language-selector
language-support
language-tools
launchpad-integration
libgksu
libgnomekbd
libgphoto2
libgweather
libindicator
liblouis
libnm-gtk
libquvi-scripts
libsensors4
libthai
libtimezonemap
libvisual-plugins-0.4
libwacom
lintian
linux-sound-base
locale
locale-langpack
locales
man
man-db
maya-calendar
menu
mibs
mime
misc
mobile-broadband-provider-info
mousetweaks
mozilla
mutter
nano
nautilus
nm-applet
noise
notify-osd
nvidia-common
omf
omf-langpack
onboard
oneconf
opencc
orca
os-prober
package-data-downloads
pam
pam-configs
pantheon
pantheon-files
perl
perl5
pinyin-database
pixmaps
pkgconfig
pkg-config-crosswrapper
plank
pnm2ppa
polkit-1
ppd
ppp
pulseaudio
purple
pygtk
pyshared
python
python-apt
readline
recovery-mode
rsyslog
samba
scratch
sgml
sgml-base
shotwell
simple-scan
snmp
software-center
software-properties
sounds
speech-dispatcher
sqlheavy
ssl-cert
system-config-printer
sysv-rc
tabset
telepathy
terminfo
themes
thumbnailers
totem
ubufox
ubuntu-sso-client
unattended-upgrades
unity-greeter
update-manager
update-notifier
usb_modeswitch
vala
vim
webkitgtk-3.0
X11
xgreeters
xml
xml-core
xsessions
xul-ext
yelp
yelp-xsl
zenity
zoneinfo
```